# Segmentation fault when introducing a second for loop

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

This program takes a number from a file and introduces a matrix `n * n` (`n` is the number taken) which all the matrix is 0.

The problem is that if I just do one `for` which only do `00, 11, 22, ...` there isn't any problem, the problem appears when I introduce the second `for`. The program returns me a segment violation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE* fitxer;
  int n, m, i,j;
  int inc[n][n];
  fitxer=fopen(argv[1], "rt");      

  if(fitxer == NULL)
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: el fitxer %s no es pot obrir\n", argv[1]); 
   return 1;
  }
  else
  {
     if(!fscanf(fitxer, "%d %d", &n, &m));

     printf("%d, %d\n", n, m);

     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
       for(j=0; j<n; j++)
       {
         inc[i][j]=0;
         printf("%d  ", inc[i][j]);
       }
     }
     printf("\n");


  }

  fclose(fitxer);       
  printf("Bien!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int inc[n][n];` <-- `n` is uninitialized and why do you have an `if` which does nothing(`if(!fscanf(fitxer, "%d %d", &n, &m));`)?

Comment: What's the value of n when `inc[n][n]` is declared? Why you read `n` and `m` and you use only `n`? When `n` and `inc` are declared the value of `n` is undefined. Assigning a value to `n` at runtime cannot modify the allocation of the variable `inc[n][n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
int inc[n][n];
```

`n` in uninitialized. This leads to Undefined Behavior. Move that after

```
if(!fscanf(fitxer, "%d %d", &n, &m));
```

to fix the problem. But then the `if` above makes no sense. Fix it by using:

```
if(fscanf(fitxer, "%d %d", &n, &m) != 2) //If fscanf failed to scan two integers from the file
{
    printf("Error reading from file");  //Print error message
    return 1;                           //Exit the program
}
```

Comment: (That first `if` already did not make any sense. A case of "magical thinking": Others Use This and Seems To It Work For Me...)